# Xamarin Forms: Platform specific code does not show xaml file

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a native sdk in my Xamarin Forms which does nothing. I have a xaml file behind the platform specific .cs file but the contents are not displayed.

Main file

```
private async void Video()
{
  DependencyService.Get<InterfaceFile>().GetNativeMethod();
}
```

Interface file

```
 public interface InterfaceFile
{
    void GetNativeMethod();
}
```

Native file:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(Demo))]
namespace Demo.Droid
{
  public partial class Demo : InterfaceFile
  {
    public string GetNativeMthod()
    {
       /// code
    }
  }
}
```

The above platform specific code has video implementation using third party native sdks. I have xaml code behind this file. 
I want to start this video call in this xaml file, which is not happening. How to bind the xaml file to .cs file?

**Edit**

I have tried removing the xaml code, and added only .cs file with following code(using Vidyo native sdk):

```
public void GetNativeMethod()
{
 _vidyoConnector = new Connector(viewHandle,Connector.ConnectorViewStyle.ConnectorviewstyleDefault, 16, "warning all@VidyoConnector info@VidyoClient", "", 0);
 _vidyoConnector.ShowViewAt(viewHandle, 0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight);
 _vidyoConnector.Connect(host, token, displayName, resourceId, this);
}
```

With above code, app crashes because frame is not defined here.

Native sdk code for Connector method:

```
public Connector(IntPtr viewId, ConnectorViewStyle viewStyle, uint remoteParticipants, String logFileFilter, String logFileName, ulong userData){

        IntPtr nLogFileFilter = MarshalPtrToUtf8.GetInstance().MarshalManagedToNative(logFileFilter ?? string.Empty);
        IntPtr nLogFileName = MarshalPtrToUtf8.GetInstance().MarshalManagedToNative(logFileName ?? string.Empty);
        objPtr = VidyoConnectorConstructNative(ref viewId, viewStyle, remoteParticipants, nLogFileFilter, nLogFileName, userData);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(nLogFileName);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(nLogFileFilter);
        VidyoConnectorSetUserDataNative(objPtr, GCHandle.ToIntPtr(GCHandle.Alloc(this, GCHandleType.Weak)));
    }
```

Documentation reference for vidyo:     https://developer.vidyo.io/#/documentation

Comment: Is the native SDK having a View to display the Video? You have to use CustomRenderer to render native views. DependencyServices can run methods or get values. Provide the code in native to display the video.

Comment: @user What control do you use to display the video? Can you provide your simple sample here?

Comment: updated question with details